# Rmpfr will not install

Tags: r, linux

RHEL 6.6 
I installed mpfr 3.16 and updated ld.conf but I still can't get R to install the package even if I explicitly set the library and include.

```
install.packages('Rmpfr', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-mpfr-include=/usr/local/include','--with-mpfr-lib=/usr/local/lib'))
```

It seems to compile but cannot load the library

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rmpfr' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>    unable to load shared object '/opt/shiny-server/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rmpfr/libs/Rmpfr.so':
>     /opt/shiny-server/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rmpfr/libs/Rmpfr.so: undefined symbol: mpfr_digamma
>   Error: loading failed

Any suggestion on what to try next?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In centos6.9, I install `mpfr4.0.1` in `/usr/local/lib`.

The system `mpfr` is in `/usr/lib64`.

If I rename `/usr/lib64/libmpfr.so` to `/usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.bk`,
I am able to install the Rmpfr:

```
R CMD INSTALL Rmpfr.tar.gz
```

then you can rename `/usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.bk` back to `/usr/lib64/libmpfr.so`.